# How to spy on a default exported function with Jest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, spy

Suppose I have a simple file exporting a default function:

```
// UniqueIdGenerator.js
const uniqueIdGenerator = () => Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 8);

export default uniqueIdGenerator;
```

Which I would use like this:

```
import uniqueIdGenerator from './UniqueIdGenerator';
// ...
uniqueIdGenerator();
```

I want to assert in my test that this method was called while keeping the original functionality. I'd do that with `jest.spyOn` however, it requires an object as well as a function name as parameters. How can you do this in a clean way? There's a similar [GitHub issue](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1414) for `jasmine` for anyone interested.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I ended up ditching the default export:

```
// UniqueIdGenerator.js
export const uniqueIdGenerator = () => Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 8);
```

And then I could use and spy it like this:

```
import * as UniqueIdGenerator from './UniqueIdGenerator';
// ...
const spy = jest.spyOn(UniqueIdGenerator, 'uniqueIdGenerator');
```

[Some recommend](https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2018/04/10/jest-spyon-function/) wrapping them in a const object, and exporting that. I suppose you can also use a class for wrapping.

However, if you can't modify the class there's still a (not-so-nice) solution:

```
import * as UniqueIdGenerator from './UniqueIdGenerator';
// ...
const spy = jest.spyOn(UniqueIdGenerator, 'default');
```

Comment: but that only works when it's transpiled by babel through es6 modules. Won't work on CommonJS

Comment: i like `const spy = jest.spyOn(UniqueIdGenerator, 'default');` because youdont need to refactor any code and risk something happening...

Comment: This does not work for me with modules installed in node_modules. I tried second solution like this: `import * as fetchModule from 'cross-fetch'`. Then spy with `jest.spyOn(fetchmodule, 'default')`. I am getting error message: `Cannot assign to read only property 'default' of object '[object Object]'`

Comment: Thank you. Typescript/Nodejs/Jest is just a pain.

Answer (score 37):

Here is a way of doing it for a default export without modifying the import (or even needing an import in the test at all):

```
const actual = jest.requireActual("./UniqueIdGenerator");
const spy = jest.spyOn(actual, "default");
```

Comment: Cleanest answer for me

Comment: This was the only version that worked for me.

Comment: Most cleaned approach!

Comment: What's nice about this is it works well for 3rd-party libraries, as well. 

Answer (score 30):

one could also mock the import and pass the original implementation as mock implementation, like:

```
import uniqueIdGenerator from './UniqueIdGenerator'; // this import is a mock already

jest.mock('./UniqueIdGenerator.js', () => {
  const original = jest. requireActual('./UniqueIdGenerator')
  return {
     __esModule: true,
     default: jest.fn(original.default)
  }
})

test(() => {
  expect(uniqueIdGenerator).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: actually thanks to jest setting resetMocks:true by default now, this only works for the 1st test. After that the `default: jest.fn` gets reset and becomes `undefined`, so in modern jest with the default config this no longer works either without another workaround

Comment: This one works for me also with packages in node_modules. With each test you can define mock function with `uniqueIdGenerator.mockImplementation(...)`

Answer (score 13):

In some cases you have to mock the import to be able to spy the default export:

```
import * as fetch from 'node-fetch'

jest.mock('node-fetch', () => ({
  default: jest.fn(),
}))

jest.spyOn(fetch, 'default')
```

Comment: `jest.mock` isn't necessary in this usecase. You could also write `jest.spyOn(fetch, 'default').mockImplementation(jest.fn())`

Comment: @kylejw2, I am getting `Cannot assign to read only property 'default' of object '[object Object]'` when I do this.

Answer (score 12):

Use 'default' as the second argument in spyOn function.

```js
import * as MyHelperMethod from '../myHelperMethod';

jest.spyOn(MyHelperMethod, 'default');
```

Answer (score 10):

Mock only the default export, or any other export, but **keep remaining exports** in module as original:

```
import myDefault, { myFunc, notMocked } from "./myModule";

jest.mock("./myModule", () => {
  const original = jest.requireActual("./myModule");
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    ...original,
    default: jest.fn(),
    myFunc: jest.fn()
  }
});

describe('my description', () => {
  it('my test', () => {
    myFunc();
    myDefault();
    expect(myFunct).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(myDefault).toHaveBeenCalled();
    
    myDefault.mockImplementation(() => 5);
    expect(myDefault()).toBe(5);
    expect(notMocked()).toBe("i'm not mocked!");
  })
});
```

Comment: Beautiful answer, very helpful.

Comment: Very nice! Personally, I still needed to have the default method returning its original value so I called it inside `jest.fn()` like: `default: jest.fn((...args) => original(...args))`.

Comment: Great answer. It solves the whole problem in a very clear way.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was a combination of the answer from [Janne Annala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64026999/1423825) and OP's own solution. All I wanted to test was that the helper method was called with the correct parameters as I had already written a test for the helper method and it didn't have any bearing on my subsequent test:

```
// myHelperMethod.js

export const myHelperMethod = (param1, param2) => { // do something with the params };
```

```js
// someOtherFileUsingMyHelperMethod.js

import * as MyHelperMethod from '../myHelperMethod';


jest.mock('../myHelperMethod', () => ({
  myHelperMethod: jest.fn(),
}));

let myHelperMethodSpy = jest.spyOn(MyHelperMethod, 'myHelperMethod');

// ...
// some setup
// ...

test(() => {
  expect(myHelperMethodSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(param1, param2);
});
```

Comment: Downvoted because it doesn't address the crux of the original question - how to do this with default exports

Comment: Despite the fact that OP themselves opted to ditch the default export in their own accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is even simpler.

Mock your exported module 'addDelay' (has the `sleep` function in it) using `jest`.

```
const { sleep } = require('../../src/utils/addDelay');

jest.mock('../../src/utils/addDelay', () => {
const delay = jest.requireActual('../../src/utils/addDelay');
return {
  ...delay,
  sleep: jest.fn(),
};});
```

And the test is as follows and check if `sleep` function was called with 1 sec as in arg.

```
test("Should delay 1 second if Okta user has no IDxM Roles", async () => {
    // GIVEN
    const MockSleep = sleep;

    // WHEN
    await getUser(req, res);
    
    // THEN
    expect(MockSleep).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1000);// sleep(1000): 1sec
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the party but I recently had this problem and wanted to share my solution as well ... though it seems a bit more unconventional but could be tweaked by someone with better knowledge.

I happen to have a file with the function that I would like to spy on.

```js
// /foo/ModuleToBeMocked.ts
const fnToSpyOn = () => ...;

export default { fnToSpyOn }
```

This is then imported into a parent file that would bring, and export, alike functions. Sort of like a classification.

```js
// /parent.ts
import fnToSpyOn from './foo/ModuleToBeMocked';
import someOtherFn from './foo/SomeOtherModule';
...

export { fnToSpyOn, someOtherFn, ... };
```

And this is how I test the `fnToSpyOn`

```js
// /foo/ModuleToBeMocked.test.ts
import { ModuleToBeMocked } from '../parent';

const fnToSpyOnSpu = jest.spyOn(ModuleToBeMocked, 'fnToSpyOn');
```

Comment: I think `export default { fnToSpyOn }` means the default export is an object containing a function, which easily fits `spyOn`.  Doesn't answer OP's question where it's `export default fnToSpyOn`

Answer (score 0):

The solution by the user [thisismydesign](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2771889/thisismydesign)(the first answer) didn't work for me. I made a few modifications to get to work.

First, I exported a default object:

```
// UniqueIdGenerator.js
const uniqueIdGenerator = () => Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 8);
export default {uniqueIdGenerator}
```

To use it, I did it as follows:

```
import generator from './UniqueIdGenerator';
// ...
const spy = jest.spyOn(generator, 'uniqueIdGenerator');
```