# How to mock a function used inside React Hook application using Enzyme and Jest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

I have React hooks component, which uses a Material table to render data. And the data is being fetched from the server. I need to test the component to see if the table has data by mocking the Api call. Below is the current code.

*dataPopulate.js* --

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';
const dataPopulate = () => {
 const [tableLoaded, setTableLoaded] = useState(false)
 const tableRef = useRef()
 // will try to mock the below function in enzyme jest. But not able to. :(
 const data = (query) => 
  new Promise(resolve, reject) => {
    axios.post('https://datastoremock/getdata')
    .then(response => { 
        const result = []
         response.data.forEach(record => 
         result.push({
             recordKey: record[0],
             instId: record[1]
         })
         )
    })
  }
 return (
     <Grid>
        <MaterialTable data={data} columns={...hasSomething} tableRef={tableRef}/>
     </Grid>
 )
}

export default dataPopulate
```

I tried testing the above by mocking the function **data** but it doesn't seem to work.

```
import DataPopulate from './dataPopulate'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'

const spy=jest.spyOn(DataPopulate, 'data') // I get a error here saying 'cannot spy on data property as it is not a function; undefined given instead
spy.mockReturnValue(JSON.parse(`[{'recordKey':'2','instId':'4'}]`))

describe('Table check', () => {
   let component = mount(<DataPopulate/>)
})
```

When I try mocking using jest.spyOn, I get an error saying that '**data**' is not a function and the value is undefined. Not sure why, as data is a function in the 'dataPopulate' component which fetches details from the server. Any idea?

Comment: Are you properly exporting the function?

Comment: Do you mean dataPopulate? Yes, i am exporting.

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky to test spy on default export, this solution might help
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54245672/15197395

Comment: this seems to be a COMMENT, not an ANSWER. you can get more reputation points by working thru the Tour page for this site ... [*grin*]

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you cannot mock a function defined within a component. The way you try to mock it `const spy=jest.spyOn(DataPopulate, 'data')` works for methods of a class you **import in a component file**.

Secondly, you usually want to do async actions (such as `POST` request) in `useEffect` hook.

About testing - in such case you would want to mock `axios` itself - I'm sure you will find many articles for the case, e.g. [this one](https://www.robinwieruch.de/axios-jest)