# fireEvent.change does not trigger onChange listener

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I am building a React component that has an input "file" type element.

```js
export default function NavBar() {
    return (
       <label htmlFor='upload-image' className={classes.label}> Upload </label>
       <input type='file' 
              id='upload-image'
              onChange={ (e) => { uploadImage(e) } } />
    )
}
```

`uploadImage` is a standalone function, exported from `uploadImage.js`:

```js
// uploadImage.js

const uploadImage = async (e) => {
    // some code to upload the image to a cloud database
}

export { uploadImage };
```

With Jest and React Testing Library, I am trying to test whether uploadImage is triggered whenever the input "file" type element is changed. Below is my work so far:

```js
import * as uploadImage from '../api/uploadImage';

test("when user changes the file input, uploadImage function is called once", () => {
    render( <NavBar /> );

    const fileInput = screen.getByLabelText(/Upload/i);

    fireEvent.change(fileInput, {
        target: {
            files: [new File(['(⌐□_□)'], 'chucknorris.png', {type: 'image/png'})],
        },
    });

    const mock = jest.spyOn(uploadImage, 'uploadImage');
    expect(mock).toBeCalled();
});
```

I expect the test to pass. When fireEvent.change() is initiated, uploadImage should be initiated. However, the test fails, showing that uploadImage was not initated as follows:

```js
expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0
```

I suspect that fireEvent.change() is not working, but I am not sure. \

1. Can you give an explanation why the test did not pass?
2. For `uploadImage.js`, instead of writing `export { uploadImage }`, how should I use jest to mock `uploadImage` if I use export default, i.e `export default uploadImage`?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You may need to wait for the event to take effect. Try using [`waitFor`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor)

Comment: Hi @tromgy, thank you for your quick answer! Unfortunately, it did not work. I changed ```expect(mock).toBeCalled()``` to ```await waitFor(() =>  expect(mock).toBeCalled())```, but it did not make a difference.

Comment: For the second question, here was what suggested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68906447/17920534. It worked amazingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `spyOn` is called *after* the event is fired.

Change the test code to:

```
test('when user changes the file input, uploadImage function is called once', () => {
  render(<NavBar />);
  const mock = jest.spyOn(uploadImage, 'uploadImage');
  const fileInput = screen.getByLabelText(/Upload/i);

  fireEvent.change(fileInput, {
    target: {
      files: [new File(['(⌐□_□)'], 'chucknorris.png', { type: 'image/png' })],
    },
  });

  expect(mock).toBeCalled();
});
```

so that the mock function is created and ready before it gets called.

Comment: Hi @tromgy, this works like a charm. Thank you!