# How do you spy on axios with jest without mocking out the whole library?

Tags: node.js, typescript, axios, jestjs

Essentially I'm trying to know whether or not axios was called with the correct args in this example:

```ts
import HttpRequestMock from 'http-request-mock';
import axios, { AxiosPromise } from 'axios';

const url = 'https://example.com';

// myFile.ts
// Private function that isn't exposed
async function businessLogic(): Promise<AxiosPromise<unknown>> {
  return axios({  // How do I know this has been called from jest?
    method: 'put',
    url,
  });
}

export async function myCoolEndpoint(): Promise<void> {
  const res = await businessLogic();
  console.log(res.data);
}
```

```ts
// myFile.test.ts
describe('sendUploadRequest', () => {
  const HTTP_MOCK = HttpRequestMock.setupForUnitTest('node');
  HTTP_MOCK.put(url, { foo: 1 }, { status: 200 });
  const spy = jest.spyOn(axios, 'Axios');

  it('can handle this large response', async () => {
    await myCoolEndpoint();

    // This fails
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

I've been unable to find anyone being able spy on axios when it is called this way, without mocking out the entire library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to spy on a default exported function with Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54245654/283366)

Comment: it does not which is why I ended up asking this question. I'm unable to spy on the default export

Comment: Did you try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70115321/283366). What happens when you do? Does it not work?

Comment: it does not work. `expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();` returns 0 even after requiring actual and spying on it.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to show exactly what you tried with that, just so it's perfectly clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achive the desire behaviour you should do the following changes to your code:

Replace
`axios({  method: 'put',url})`
with
`axios.request({  method: 'put',url})`

Replace `expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();` with `expect(axios.request).toHaveBeenCalled();`

You don't have to save the return of the spyOn method

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a wrapper file for http methods where you can reuse the http code, something like:

```
export function httpPut<T = any, R = any>(
  url: string,
  data: T,
): Promise<AxiosResponse<R>> {
  return axios({
    method: 'put',
    url,
    data: data,
  })
}

export function httpGet<R = any>(
  url: string
): Promise<AxiosResponse<R>> {
  return axios({
    method: 'get',
    url,
  })
}

// and so on
```

Then in my jest files I do the mock of the http wrapper functions

```
describe('test suite', () => {
  const httpMock: any = {}

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules()
    jest.doMock('../path/to/wrapper/httpFile', () => httpMock)
  })

  it('test you http call', async () => {
    // set up the expected response 
    httpMock.httpPut = jest.fn(() => [
      { status: 200, data: { /* expected response */ }, /* any more axios stuff */ },
    ])

    await myCoolEndpoint();

    expect(httpMock.httpPut).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(httpMock.httpPut).toBeCalledWith(/* expected params */);
  })
})
```

That way you wouldn't be mocking the entire axios library only the http wrapper functions and you can throw different errors and see how the function behaves

Hope this helps, cheers

Comment: this still replaces (mocks) the implementation of the requests which is what I'm trying to avoid. Also creating wrappers like this introduces a tonne of code duplication for no gain when you can just pass axios what method you want